# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Framework Files Not Found

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I have just downloaded VS 2017 Enterprise and selected the mobile development with .NET option, I noticed that all my old project that targets a Xamarin framework (Xamarin.iOS for example) doesn't have any target framework option available and I have checked Reference Assemblies folder and noticed that no xamarin farmework was installed only .NET framework

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it
Manually copy the folders in

***system drive*:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework** to  ***system driver *:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework**